# Check if a user is a member of a public group

Tags: force.com, validation

I want a validation rule to fire if a user is a member of a public group. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible as far as I know. It would require a SOQL query to get the groups the user is in. This is a many to many relationship and typically that type of thing isn't accessible in formulas.

Comment: so if i have a validation rule/formula, I need to add each user id manually? Is there a better way? Because if you add/inactivate users then you need to add thier ID to to those rules in QA ... (which means you need to set up users in QA too)

Comment: If this validation is absolutely necessarily, it would be much easier to just do it in Apex as a trigger. Like I stated in the answer, it is impossible to get the public group so unless you do this ID work around (which I don't recommend), the Apex trigger is the better solution.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as such. We want to keep our answer rate high (we need 90%+ to get out of beta)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly check if the user is a member of a public group in a validation rule or workflow. However, there is a reasonable alternative without having to resort to writing a trigger.

1. Create a Custom Permission that is named something relevant: "Fire XXX Workflow"
2. Create a Permission Set that is named similarly: "Allow Fire XXX Workflow"
3. Add the Custom Permission created in step 1 to the Permission
   Set. (You can also assign it to existing profiles/permission sets if appropriate)
4. In the Workflow or Validation rule, use the "Formula
   Evaluates to True" setting. Then use $Permission->Fire_XXX_Workflow
   as part of the criteria. (You can use the "Insert Field" button to
   pick the permission).
5. Add the users to the Permission Set created in step 2
6. Optionally create a Delegated Admin Group and allow it to assign users the Permission set so that managers can maintain the users.